# Merging event horizontally in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm developing a non-comercial application for managing absences, using FullCalendar. It has 2 views: month and week-based. In the week view there are rows for employees and columns for days. I'm displaying absences that employees requested.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/35aRH.png

I want to merge absence (it's a FullCalendar event) into one line, so there aren't any blank spaces between them like on the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NWrS.png

What is the proper way of doing this?